# select xml nodes using xpath syntax confusion

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Given the xml below why does the first selectsinglenode call not work but the second one does? Are the single quotes specifying a string type or something?

```vb
Dim dbglvlnode As Xml.XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("Config/Scanner[DeviceID = '{0}']/DebugLevel", XMLstuff.DeviceID))
Dim dbglvlnode As Xml.XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("Config/Scanner[DeviceID = {0}]/DebugLevel", XMLstuff.DeviceID))
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Config>
 <Scanner>
  <!--Test Scanner-->
  <DeviceID>00199</DeviceID>
  <DeviceNumber>0099</DeviceNumber>
  <DebugLevel>10</DebugLevel>
 </Scanner>
</Config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach would lead to an XPath expression sort of like this:

```
Config/Scanner[DeviceID = '00199']/DebugLevel
```

This would return the DebugLevel element of the first Scanner in Config for which the DeviceID element has textual value `00199`

Your second approach would lead to an XPath expression like this:

```
Config/Scanner[DeviceID = 00199]/DebugLevel
```

This would return the DebugLevel element of the first Scanner in Config for which the DeviceID element has the **numeric** value `00199`.

The difference is that the first approach would only match `00199` exactly, so if `XMLstuff.DeviceID` is an integer or a string with value `199`, it won't work. The second approach will work as long as the element's content evaluates to an integer with the right value. So yes, the single quotes identify that right-hand portion of the comparison as text.

XPath is rather lenient in converting data types and doing comparisons.

Comment: that makes sense now. My xmlstuff.deviceID property is an integer and when I read it in from the xml file it drops the leading 00's and thus why the comparison failed.